# Fix inaccurate reported error with ReSharper 9.0

Tags: resharper, resharper-9.0

I have recently installed ReSharper 9.0 for use with VS 2010 from version 7 and am now seeing reported problems and error with RS that are not correct.  These are all in the .cshtml files.  First, for something like

```
 $(".previous").prop("disabled", true);
```

The named class previous is kind of greyed out and the warning is that the class is never used, but it is.  How do I fix this and get RS to not report this wrong warning?

The next problem is more severe.  I have a line in the HTML like

```
 <input class="last" type="button" id="btnLast" onclick="last()" value=">>" />
```

from this line down in the file are nothing but red lines on the side panel and wrong errors like tag table not closed, tag div not closed, and so on.  If I remove the ">>" then everything is fine in the file.  Is there a new setting that I cannot find for RS 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First analysis often gives false positive results, so it will be removed in upcoming 9.1 version.

Second issue is already logged in our tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-429055. Over there workaround is provided. In short - use html entities.

```
<input class="last" type="button" id="btnLast" onclick="last()" value="&gt;&gt;" />
```

Comment: For those who don't know what an HTML entity is, could you edit your answer with the OP's `input` element but changed so that ReSharper doesn't complain?